# assign values to rings in archery targets python3

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I have an archery target with 5 rings (or 4 rings and a central circle). I have to give each of those rings a score. The scores would be (for the rings outside to inside): 1-2-5-10-25

Before I heard what the specific scores would be, I made this function to assign scores to each ring:

```
def points(cDistance):
    for i in range(5):
        if i <= cDistance < i+1:
            return 10-2*i
```

Notes: cDistance is the distance from the mouse click to the center of the target. Each ring and the middle circle has a radius of 1. 
**EDIT :**
The scores returned here are not the correct scores for this assignment.

I already figured out the scores for the rings get multiplied by 2 and then by 2.5. I don't know how to neatly put this in a for-loop. I can make an if statement for each ring, but I think that looks ugly and I should be able to make it shorter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, I don't think your score calculation is correct, but that's another issue.

Comment: You can use the [`math` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) functions `ceil` or `floor` to make things easier: if used correctly, there's no need for an iteration and if statement.

Comment: And using an array with the scores, you can simply index it: `[1, 2, 5, 10, 25][math.floor(cDistance)]` (ignoring what happens at the borders of the rings, or when hit outside of the target).

Comment: my score calculation is indeed not correct, because that is the problem I am trying to solve. I will edit my question a bit to make this clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function working as it should:

```
def points(cDistance):
    if cDistance <= 5:
        return [25, 10, 5, 2, 1][math.floor(cDistance)]
```

If the cDistance is under 1 the function returns 25, if cDistance is under 2 it returns 10 etc.

I had to add the if statement, or I would get an error if I clicked outside of the target. Now, when clicking outside the target, it returns `None`. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly wrong in this case with an if-elif-...-else chain, especially if you want to deal with the situation where the arrow lands outside the target (which could be the else part).

Otherwise, index an array like:

```
score = [1, 2, 5, 10, 25][math.floor(cDistance)]
```

Wrap it in a `try`-`except IndexError` to handle cases for larger distances. And if you want to go all the way, you can first make sure cDistance is always 0 or larger:

```
scores = [1, 2, 5, 10, 25]
dist = max(0, cDistance)
dist = math.floor(dist)
try:
    score = scores[dist]
except IndexError:
    score = 0
```

Or you can use a dict (a dict can use integer keys, so it's nearly the same as an array, except that you can use `get()` with a default value for incorrect distances):

```
scores = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 10, 4: 25}
dist = max(0, cDistance)
dist = math.floor(dist)
score = scores.get(dist, 0)
```

NB: `int(dist)` results in exactly the same value (and type) as `math.floor(dist)` for positive values.